# Quaternion rotation in three.js going haywire when rotating past about 90°

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation, multi-touch, quaternions

I'm using two-finger touch events to pinch-rotate-zoom a `THREE.Mesh` object, using quaternions. It's my first time using this rotation method, and due to I'm sure some property of quaternions that I can't seem to understand, the rotation gradually starts to jitter all over the place when the total touch drag rotates the object over about 90°. Then, it gradually returns to the original smooth, albeit noticeably nonlinear, rotation when dragged back under 90° again. (90° is just a guess).

I'm completely stumped. Here is the code I'm using to rotate the object `obj`:

```
  // global state
var 
      // keeps track of original object scale
    pinchScale = new THREE.Vector3(),

      // current first touch
    touch1 = new THREE.Vector2(),

      // current second touch
    touch2 = new THREE.Vector2(),

      // first touch at touch start
    touch1OnHold = new THREE.Vector2(),

      // second touch at touch start
    touch2OnHold = new THREE.Vector2(),

      // keeps track of total held rotation at last fired touchmove event
    angularHoldPrev = new THREE.Quaternion();

  ⋮

  // key-value pairs inside an addEventListener utility
touchstart: function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if ( event.touches.length === 1 ) {
    …
  } else if ( event.touches.length === 2 ) {
    touch1OnHold.set(event.touches[0].pageX, event.touches[0].pageY);
    touch2OnHold.set(event.touches[1].pageX, event.touches[1].pageY);
    angularHoldPrev.set(0, 0, 0, 1)
  }
},
touchmove: function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if ( event.touches.length === 1 ) {
    …
  } else if ( event.touches.length === 2 ) {
    touch1.set(event.touches[0].pageX, event.touches[0].pageY);
    touch2.set(event.touches[1].pageX, event.touches[1].pageY);
    var 
          // get touch spread at present event firing, and at the start of current hold
        touchDiff = touch2.clone().sub(touch1),
        touchDiffOnHold = touch2OnHold.clone().sub(touch1OnHold),

          // camera is on z-axis; get this axis regardless of obj orientation
        axis1 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1).applyQuaternion(obj.quaternion.clone().inverse()),

          // get a touch rotation around this axis
        rot1 = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(axis1, (Math.atan2(touchDiffOnHold.y, touchDiffOnHold.x) - Math.atan2(touchDiff.y, touchDiff.x))).normalize(),

          // get touch barycentre at present event firing, and at the start of current hold
        touchCentre = touch1.clone().add(touch2).multiplyScalar(.5),
        touchCentreOnHold = touch1OnHold.clone().add(touch2OnHold).multiplyScalar(.5),

          // get axis of touch barycentre movement on the xy plane, regardless of obj orientation
        axis2 = new THREE.Vector3(touchCentre.y - touchCentreOnHold.y, touchCentre.x - touchCentreOnHold.x, 0).applyQuaternion(obj.quaternion.clone().inverse()),

          // get a rotation proportional to magnitude of touch movement
        rot2 = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(axis2, axis2.length() * rotationSensitivity).normalize(),

          // combine the two rotations
        rot = rot1.multiply(rot2);

      // undo last rotation if not the empty quaternion
    if (!angularHoldPrev.equals(new THREE.Quaternion())) obj.quaternion.multiply(angularHoldPrev.inverse());

      // perform the currently calculated rotation
    obj.quaternion.multiply(rot);

      // save this rotation for next event firing
    angularHoldPrev.copy(rot);

      // resize object according to change in touch spread
    obj.scale.copy(pinchScale.clone().multiplyScalar(touchDiff.length() / touchDiffOnHold.length()))
  }
},
touchend: function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

    // reset original object scale
  pinchScale.copy(obj.scale)
}
```

Any clue how I can maintain proportional rotation for all two-touch input would be greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: A quick guess without looking deeply is probably your atan2. The tan function zips off to infinity at 90 degrees.

Comment: I was worried about that. However atan2 doesn't have any infinities, only a discontinuity between positive and negative 180°.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by making all the touchmove rotations incremental rather than relative to touchstart, and it actually cleans things up a little. `rotV` is an angular velocity variable I have for the animation loop that gives the object a nice inertial kick when you move it around. (Thanks @WestLangley for the optimisation advice)

```
var touch1 = new THREE.Vector2(),
    touch2 = new THREE.Vector2(),
    touch1Prev = new THREE.Vector2(),
    touch2Prev = new THREE.Vector2(),
    rotV = new THREE.Quaternion(),

    touchDiff = new THREE.Vector2(),
    touchDiffPrev = new THREE.Vector2(),
    touchCentre = new THREE.Vector2(),
    touchCentrePrev = new THREE.Vector2(),
    axis1 = new THREE.Vector3(),
    axis2 = new THREE.Vector3(),
    rot1 = new THREE.Quaternion(),
    rot2 = new THREE.Quaternion(),
    adjq = new THREE.Quaternion();

⋮

touchstart: function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if ( event.touches.length === 1 ) {
    …
  } else if ( event.touches.length === 2 ) {
    touch1Prev.set(event.touches[0].pageX, event.touches[0].pageY);
    touch2Prev.set(event.touches[1].pageX, event.touches[1].pageY)
  }
},
touchmove: function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  adjq.copy(obj.quaternion).inverse();
  if ( event.touches.length === 1 ) {
    …
  } else if ( event.touches.length === 2 ) {
    touch1.set(event.touches[0].pageX, event.touches[0].pageY);
    touch2.set(event.touches[1].pageX, event.touches[1].pageY);

    touchDiff.copy(touch2).sub(touch1);
    touchDiffPrev.copy(touch2Prev).sub(touch1Prev);
    axis1.set(0, 0, 1).applyQuaternion(adjq);
    rot1.setFromAxisAngle(axis1, (Math.atan2(touchDiffPrev.y, touchDiffPrev.x) - Math.atan2(touchDiff.y, touchDiff.x))).normalize();

    touchCentre.copy(touch1).add(touch2).multiplyScalar(.5);
    touchCentrePrev.copy(touch1Prev).add(touch2Prev).multiplyScalar(.5);
    axis2.set(touchCentre.y - touchCentrePrev.y, touchCentre.x - touchCentrePrev.x, 0).applyQuaternion(adjq);
    rot2.setFromAxisAngle(axis2, axis2.length() * rotationSensitivity * 10).normalize();

    obj.quaternion.multiply(rot1.multiply(rot2));
    rotV.multiply(rot1.slerp(adjq.set(0, 0, 0, 1), .9));
    obj.scale.multiplyScalar(touchDiff.length() / touchDiffPrev.length());

    touch1Prev.copy(touch1);
    touch2Prev.copy(touch2)
  }
},
touchend: function (event) {
  event.preventDefault()
}
```

I still wish I knew what caused the original problem though :P

Comment: Avoid calling `new` and `clone()` in tight loops. Create a single instance and reuse it. How many instances are you creating per `touchmove`?

Comment: Thanks for that @WestLangley , I've updated my answer. Also I notice you actually wrote a lot of the quaternion code in three.js. Do you see anything glaring that I've overlooked?

Comment: I can answer questions about three.js, but I can't comment on your code. Sorry. :)

Comment: While I can't tell you how to 'fix' it, I can tell you what's the problem 'around 90°' through a problem of mine. The thing with Quaternions (And with the Euler represenation too) that they have discontinuities. Let's say you have two points near the "north pole" right around at (x: 0 y:0 z:1) if we're talking about unit spheres. You want to rotate between these two points that even though "right next to each other" one of them has a 'x' rotation of '-178' and the other a '+178'. (180 is the top) In my case TWEEN thinks (rightfully so) that the shortest route between -178 and 178 is through 0.